# How do you change the default status message that shows when one submits a profile form?

Tags: profile, forms

At the moment it says 'Thank you. Your information has been saved' after one submits a form. I can't work out where to change this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is hardcoded in CRM/Profile/Form/Edit.php, so you would need to modify that.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the Word Replacements functionality to change this.